# IIS Manager show no certificate, but can see in registry and browsers can use it

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate, windows-server-2016

Using Windows Server 2016. I'm inspecting the bindings of some existing websites using IIS Manager.  On the "Edit Site Binding" dialog for an https binding, the SSL Certificate dropdown displays "Not selected".  However, I can see a certificate binding in the registry (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters\SslBindingInfo`). In Certificate Manager the expected certificate looks healthy and I see the `You have a private key that corresponds to this certificate` message. When I browse to the site (Firefox 117.0.1 on Windows) I can make an SSL connection and the browser thinks the certificate is fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to run a report to confirm, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html